# How to create custom slivers in flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, responsive-design

I want to create a custom container under the sliver appbar like the right screen in the image

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1720296/screenshots/6918712/dribbble_blog_2x.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom header with `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`,

This is your custom `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`

```
class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {

  @override
  double get minExtent => 100;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => 300;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      ...
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```
SliverPersistentHeader(
  delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
    ...
  ),
  pinned: true,
),
```